# How to round mysql column in a table output

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I need to round a result of a SQL round in a table array output.  I can't figure out the syntax...

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `Energ_Kcal`*`yield`*`qty` AS `cal` FROM allinnot a
WHERE `own_id` = $user->id");

    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['Shrt_Desc'] . "</td><td>&nbsp;" . $row['desc'] . "</td><td>" . $row['cal'] . " cal</td></tr>";
```

`cal` returns a value with many numerals beyond the decimal.  I just need it to show a whole rounded integer.  I tried ROUND(), but I must be putting it in the wrong place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

general syntax

```
ROUND( expression, 2 )
```

Comment: UGH, thanks! i was trying to round with the AS `cal` inside, too.  ROUND(`Energ_Kcal`*`yield`*`qty` ) AS `cal` works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

The ROUND should go around the values, try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ROUND(`Energ_Kcal`*`yield`*`qty`,2) AS `cal` FROM allinnot a
WHERE `own_id` = $user->id");

    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['Shrt_Desc'] . "</td><td>&nbsp;" . $row['desc'] . "</td><td>" . $row['cal'] . " cal</td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also check out PHP's [`round()`](http://php.net/round) or, possibly from your description [`int_val()`](http://php.net/int_val).